# Filtering an array of products

Tags: reactjs, filter, react-functional-component

I'm a newbie and I try to set up a search engine that will render the products, base on the value I type on the input.

With my code below, I tried that way but it seems that my logic isn't correct.
Could someone go through my code and check it out and can give me some insight afterward, please.

Thank you in advance.

```
import data from "./utils/data";

const App = () => {
  const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState("");

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setSearchValue(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <SearchInput handleChange={handleChange} searchValue={searchValue} />
      <Products data={data} searchValue={searchValue} />
    </div>
  );
};


const SearchInput = ({ searchValue, handleChange }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Search specific item..."
        value={searchValue}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default SearchInput;

    
function Products({ data, searchValue }) {
  const [productsInfo, setProductsInfo] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    filteredProducts(data);
  }, []);

  const filteredProducts = (products) => {
    if (searchValue.toLowerCase().trim() === "") {
      setProductsInfo(products);
    } else {
      const seekedItem = productsInfo.filter(
        (product) =>
          product.name.toLowerCase().trim().includes(searchValue) ===
          searchValue.toLowerCase().trim()
      );
      setProductsInfo(seekedItem);
    }
  };

  const productsData =
    productsInfo.length <= 0 ? (
      <div>Loading...</div>
    ) : (
      <div>
        {productsInfo.map((product, index) => {
          return (
            <div
              key={index}
              style={{ backgroundColor: "grey", maxWidth: "300px" }}
            >
              <h4>{product.name}</h4>
              <p>{product.category}</p>
              <p> {product.price} </p>
              <hr />
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );

  return productsData;
}

export default Products;

const data = [
  {
    category: "Sporting Goods",
    price: "$49.99",
    stocked: true,
    name: "Football",
  },
  {
    category: "Sporting Goods",
    price: "$9.99",
    stocked: true,
    name: "Baseball",
  },
  {
    category: "Sporting Goods",
    price: "$29.99",
    stocked: false,
    name: "Basketball",
  },
  {
    category: "Electronics",
    price: "$99.99",
    stocked: true,
    name: "iPod Touch",
  },
  {
    category: "Electronics",
    price: "$399.99",
    stocked: false,
    name: "iPhone 5",
  },
  { category: "Electronics", price: "$199.99", stocked: true, name: "Nexus 7" },
];

export default data;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you return empty array in second params in useEffect This function fired only once. Try that:

```
useEffect(() => {
filteredProducts(data);

  }, [searchValue]);
```

Answer (score 0):

.includes return true or false (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)

Try that:

```
const filteredProducts = (products) => {
if (searchValue.toLowerCase().trim() === "") {
  setProductsInfo(products);
} else {
  const seekedItem = productsInfo.filter(
    (product) =>
      product.name.toLowerCase().trim().includes(searchValue)
  );
  setProductsInfo(seekedItem);
}
```

};